# Uses of characterization of $\sigma$-finiteness

Tags: measure-theory

It's not difficult to prove the following characterization of $\sigma$-finite measures: Let $(\Omega, \mathscr A, \mu)$ be a measure space. Then,
$$ \Omega \text{ is } \sigma\text{-finite} \iff \text{there exists a measurable } f > 0 \text{ with } \int_\Omega f \ d \mu < \infty.$$
My question: Is this just a common practice problems for students to get familiar with $\sigma$-finite spaces or do you know any situations where this fact came in handy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it serves as "motivation": we want to study $\sigma$-finite measures so at least we have some non-trivial integrals for positive functions. As integrals are  functionals for some function spaces, this shows that in those cases we have at least some non-trivial functionals. It justifies why we often have $\sigma$-finiteness as an assumption in theorems.

Comment: Great answer! Motivation is at least as important (or even more important) than simple applications for me!